# Do I need external 2nd level cache for multiple NHibernate instances in Windows Azure?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, caching, azure, memcached

I am developing *AMF Flash* gateway on *[FlourineFx](http://www.fluorinefx.com/)* application for deployment on *Windows Azure* and I want to use *Azure SQL*.

I use *[NHibernate 2.1](http://nhforge.org/)* + *NHibernate.Linq 1.0* + *FluentNHibernate 1.1*

There will be two or more instances of this FlourineFx gateway and only 1 database.

I am planning on implementing *[memcached](http://memcached.org/)* as 2nd level cache later (as Windows Azure WorkerRole), but is it necessary?
(I don't mind performance, but I do mind consistency)

Comment: How would a L2 cache improve consistency of... of what by the way?

Comment: consistency could not be the right word - I am worried about DB, what happens if there are connections from multiple instances of NHibernate. I don't know if 2nd level cache solves some transaction-related problems or just makes it faster (maybe this should be the question and hopefully I would tell myself what idiot I was)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, you don't.**

But, how you guys helped me point to the right direction, it will help with performance.
So I will definitely run some instances of `memcached` and investigate concurrency control further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know if 2nd level cache solves some transaction-related problems or just makes it faster

The main point of the L2 cache is to avoid database hits and I wouldn't say that the L2 cache solves transactions-related problems; It might just be involved (and thus make the whole process a bit more complicated), if fully transactional caches are supported by NHibernate.

Personally, I tend to limit the use of L2 caching to read-only (or mostly read) objects, that's where the L2 cache gives all its power. Caching read-write entities is trickier, especially in a clustered environment, and the cache provider [must support](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=982286&start=0) the Cache Concurrency Strategy required by your application for a given entity (read-only, non-strict-read-write, read-write).

I'm not sure this really answers the question, but at least it might give you some hints.

#### References

- [17.2. The Second Level Cache](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-cache)
- [Chapter 23, NHibernate.Caches](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#caches)

Comment: Thanks. Seems that I want to use NHibernate.Caches.MemCache and CloudCache [http://cloudcache.codeplex.com] or Velocity [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/velocity]

Answer (score 1):

The cache won't help you with consistency. Of course it *will* help with performance, and you should use a distributed one, like memcached, if running multiple instances, as you correctly inferred.

That said, NHibernate does have features to help with consistency. Check:

- [5.1.7. version](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-version)
- [10.4. Optimistic concurrency control](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-optimistic)